# Table doesn't take 100% if I change display to block

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-7

I have a very simple html:

```
    <table id="root" >
        <tr>
        <th>Version</th>
        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>Operation Type</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>390</td>
        <td>vr32090</td>
        <td>U</td>
        <td>2012-09-12 19:41:19:129</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>389</td>
        <td>vr32090</td>
        <td>U</td>
        <td>2012-09-12 19:41:04:554</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<style>

#root {
    width:100%;
}

</style>

<script>
    document.getElementById("root").style.display = "block";
</script>
```

if I comment out the script part, the table takes 100% as per style, but if the script is executed the table takes only the needed space. How do I fix this? I need the script, it's a part of more complicated page, I made it as simple as possible to illustrate the problem.

P.S. Ok, this could be fixed by making display = "table". The issue is that I need to use it in IE7 and it doesn't support this display type. What can I do to make it 100% in IE7 as well?

Comment: Tables have their own value for `display` - "table", not "block".

Comment: got it, that was exactly the problem

Comment: Actually, I need this to work in IE7, is there a way to make it work there?

Comment: Surround the table with a div.